# Flush TLB on a context swtich

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, context-switch, tlb, page-tables

This may depends on the OS, but in general as I understand that when there a page fault (the desired page is not in main memory) occurs OS will instruct CPU to read the page from disk, and I am wondering does OS dispatch to another process while the disk I/O ? if it does then there will be a complete flushing of the TLB on a context switch, correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More or less, but a page fault doesn't always mean the page is on the disk (it could also not exist at all, be a lazy-allocation page, be a copy-on-write page that was written to, exist but be marked unreadable/unwritable, etc). But if that's how it is, it's probably going to schedule an other thread at least because disk IO takes approximately forever.

The amount of switching necessary depends on what it switches to, switching between threads from the same context doesn't imply a TLB flush. If a TLB flush is necessary, it's probably not a *complete* flush, because of global pages (so typically, you're not flushing out TLB entries for kernel pages). There is also PCID to avoid complete flushes (flushing can be limited to specified process context IDs), but that's quite recent, and tricky to use since there are only 4096 different IDs.

Comment: i see. The reason i asked about this is because after the I/O is complete the processor will update the page table as well as the TLB, so by flushing completely wouldn't really make sense i guess.

Comment: @peter it would still work though, it would be slower since you'd have lots of extra TLB misses but things wouldn't actually go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Process-specific pages are marked as non-global entries with nG(non-global) bit in TLB entry and also stores the pid(Address ID in ARM's terminology).
Now the article clearly lays out this concept.

"For non-global entries, when the TLB is updated and the entry is marked as non-global, a value is stored in the TLB entry in addition to the normal translation information. This value is called the Address Space ID (ASID), which is a number assigned by the OS to each individual task. Subsequent TLB look-ups only match on that entry if the current ASID matches with the ASID that is stored in the entry. This permits multiple valid TLB entries to be present for a particular page marked as non-global, but with different ASID values. In other words, we do not necessarily need to flush the TLBs when we context switch."

Source: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/The-Memory-Management-Unit/Context-switching